# mysql- Get self ranking compared to others in the score

Tags: mysql, sql

These are one table:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test_member order by points asc;
+-----------+---------+
| member_id | points  |
+-----------+---------+
|        34 |    1000 |
|        22 |    2000 |
|        33 |    2000 |
|        35 |    3000 |
+-----------+---------+
```

The right results:
when my member_id is '35', my rank will be '1',

when my member_id is '22', my rank will be '2',

when my member_id is '33', my rank will be '2',

when my member_id is '34', my rank will be '3',

....

and so on.

**Attempt - 1**

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT    member_id,
          @points := @points + 1 AS rank
FROM      test_member p, (SELECT @points := 0) r
ORDER BY  points DESC
  ) t
WHERE member_id='33';

+-----------+----------------------------------------+
| member_id | rank                                   |
+-----------+------------+------+---------+----------+
|     33    | 3.000000000000000000000000000000       |
+-----------+----------------------------------------+
```

**Attempt - 2 (mysql + php way)**

```
<?php
$simulation_ponits = 1000;

$sql = '
  SELECT t.points, COUNT(*) as count_num
  FROM test_member as t
  WHERE t.points > ' . $simulation_ponits . ' 
  GROUP BY t.points
  HAVING t.points > ' . $simulation_ponits .' 
';

$result = mysql_query($sql);

$count_rank = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $count_rank +=$row['count_num'];
}


+--------+-----------+
| points | count_num |
+--------+-----------+
|   2000 |         2 |
|   3000 |         1 |
+--------+-----------+


# $count_rank => 3
```

Both attempts are only mysql + php way can show right result, 
can I have other way tried to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to get a ranking, not a row number.  The following should work:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT    member_id,
            @rnk := @rnk + if (@prevPoints = points, 0,
                       if (@prevPoints := points, 1, 1)) as rnk
  FROM      test_member p, (SELECT @rnk := 0, @prevPoints := null) r
  ORDER BY  points DESC
) t
WHERE member_id = 33
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d2200/3)